# Error trying to get my GUI program to display, I have coded the entire program properly based on what Ive been taught

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter
import tkinter.messagebox


class FenceGUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.main_window = tkinter.Tk()

        self.length_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.width_frame = tkinter.Frame()
        self.button_frame = tkinter.Frame()

        self.length_label = tkinter.Label(self.length_frame,
                                             text='Enter the length:')
        self.length_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.length_frame,
                                          width=10)

        self.length_label.pack(side='left')
        self.length_entry.pack(side='left')

        self.width_label = tkinter.Label(self.width_frame,
                                         text='Enter the width:')
        self.width_entry = tkinter.Entry(self.width_frame,
                                         width=10)

        self.width_label.pack(side='left')
        self.width_entry.pack(side='left')

        self.calc_perimeter = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame,
                                          text='Permieter',
                                          command=self.perimeter)
        self.calc_area = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame,
                                        text='Area',
                                        command=self.area)
                                        
        self.quit_button = tkinter.Button(self.button_frame,
                                          text='Quit',
                                          command=self.main_window.destroy)

        self.calc_button = pack(side='left')
        self.quit_button = pack(side='left')

        self.length_frame.pack()
        self.width_frame.pack()
        self.button_frame.pack()

        tkinter.mainloop()

    def Permieter(self):
        Length = float(self.length_entry.get())
        Width = float(self.width_entry.get())

        perimeter = (Length * 2) + (Width * 2)

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('The Permieter of your fence is', perimeter)

    def Area(self):
        Length = float(self.length_entry.get())
        Width = float(self.width_entry.get())

        area = (Length * Width)

        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo('The Area of your fence is', area)


fence_calc = FenceGUI()
```

when I attempt to call get the GUI to populate I get an error stating that `FenceGUI is not defined`, I cannot figure out how to fix this I have used the same process doing other GUI programs with no issues any help?

Comment: I haven't tried running the code, but I put it through a linter, which didn't find that problem (although it did find that `pack` is undefined, which seems to be a typo, `=` instead of `.`). So are you sure this is the right code? Please provide a [mre]. You can [edit] the question. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want more tips.

Comment: `FenceGUI is not defined` - that is not the error when I run your code. I get the error `AttributeError: 'FenceGUI' object has no attribute 'perimeter'`, and that error is telling you precisely what's wrong.  Please make sure the code and the question are related to each other

Answer (score 1):

Well first you need to correctly assign the commands to your Buttons. Perimeter is spelled wrong and both aren't capitalized as the functions are defined.

so change  `def Permieter(self):`  to `def Perimeter(self):`

then in the Button definitions: `command=self.perimeter` to `command=self.Perimeter`

and `command=self.area` to `command=self.Area`

Also this whole bit needs to be updated:

```
self.calc_button = pack(side='left')
self.quit_button = pack(side='left')
```

to this:

```
#correctly use .pack() and reference the right button names
self.calc_perimeter.pack(side='left')
self.calc_area.pack(side='left')
self.quit_button.pack(side='left')
```

You should pay attention to what the errors are saying and and at what lines and this can be solved pretty easily.